# Let $X$ be Poisson random variable with mean $1$. Find $E(|X-1|)$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let  $X$ be Poisson random variable with mean $1$. Find $E(|X-1|)$

Frankly I have no idea how to attempt this one. Help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$E|X-1|=P(X=0)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(n-1)P({\{X=n\})}$. Can you do the computation now?

Comment: Should it not be the probability and not the indicator function or am I missing something ? Thanks !

Comment: @Matthieu Thanks. I was so careless when I typed the answer.

Comment: No problem. Your comments are always very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Note that 
$$
|k-1| = 1, \text{ for } k=0 \text{ w.p. } P(X=0)\\
|k-1| = 0, \text{ for } k=1 \text{ w.p. } P(X=1)\\
|k-1| = k-1, \text{ for } k \ge 1 \text{ w.p. } P(X=k)
$$

Then the expectation $E|X-1|$ becomes: $1\times e^{-\lambda}+0\times \lambda e^{-\lambda}+ \sum_{k=1}^\infty (k-1)e^{-\lambda} \lambda^ k /k!$.

Splitting the sum in two parts we get $E|X-1| = \lambda -1 + 2e^{-\lambda}.$

Answer (score 1):

The [mean absolute deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#Descriptive_statistics) about the mean of Poisson distribution is:

$$\mathbb{E}[|X-\lambda|]=2e^{-\lambda}\dfrac{\lambda^{\lfloor\lambda\rfloor+1}}{\lfloor\lambda\rfloor!}$$

where $\lfloor\lambda\rfloor$ is the floor function.

Therefore,

$$\mathbb{E}[|X-1|]=2e^{-1}$$

Answer (score 0):

The answers by Kavi Rama Murthy and QFi already give you the answer, I'll just present another approach, just for fun.

Since
$$
|X-1| = \left\{
\begin{array}{cc}
2 + X - 1 & \text{if} \ X = 0 \\
X - 1 & \text{if} \ X \geq 1
\end{array}
\right. $$

We have that
$$
E(| X - 1 |) = 2 P(X=0) + E(X - 1) 
$$

> And so
>  $$ E(| X - 1 |) = 2 P(X=0) + E(X) - E(1) $$
>  Since $E(X) = \lambda = 1$ and $E(k) = k$, for any constant $k$,
>  $$ E(| X - 1 |) = 2 e^{-1}\frac{1^0}{0!} + 1 - 1 $$
>  Simplifying gives
>  $$ E(| X - 1 |) = 2 e^{-1} $$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\lower{2ex}{\begin{align}\mathsf E(\lvert X-1\rvert)&=\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_{X=0})+\mathsf E((X-1)\mathbf 1_{X\geq 1})\\&=\mathsf P(X{=}0)+\mathsf E(X\mathbf 1_{X\geq 1})-\mathsf P(X{\ge}1)\end{align}}$